# joomla user activation email

Tags: joomla

I have an existing group of 1500 users that I want to migrate into the Joomla system so that i can take advantage of the password self service system is provides. I want to ensure that the ID of the user remains the same and that they get an activation email at the start.

From testing with Joomla is can

1 - I can create the jom_user via SQL using an INSERT statement that ensures the ID is the same but this method does not result in any activation email being sent.

2 - I can manually create the user via the 'User Manager' component, which results in the activation email being sent but the ID cannot be guaranteed.

I wondering is there a recommended method where i can create the user via SQL and then use a module or plugin to resend the activation email?

Comment: you might find the following two threads useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208376/joomla-import-users-from-csv-file/9236743#9236743  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9357404/joomla-1-7-user-registration-customization-issue/9359312#9359312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know there are components out there to resend activation emails.
As long as you brought in the user and the same password they had before you should be okay - but if you used any sort of encoding for the password (md5 is Joomlas standard IIRC)  you may run into issues.

You can check some of the [Authentication Management Methods](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-management) in the Joomla Extension Directory.  I had used one on a very active site quite a while ago (with 1.5) and it worked great to be able to send out re-activation emails to users.

That would probably be the best bet and keep you from reinventing the wheel.

If you did encode their passwords things will be a bit trickier, otherwise they may not know the 'new' password you create in Joomla for them unless you go in and physically tell them.

Good luck!